# Difference between "novice" and "newbie"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns

I can say "I am a novice in English" or "I am a newbie in English". Is there any difference between these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Newbie" is extremely informal, whereas "novice" has a somewhat old-fashioned sound to it. "Beginner" might be a better choice than either of your candidates.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the connotation. It is considered more rude to call someone a newbie than to call someone a novice. Also, a newbie could be someone new to something rather than a novice being someone who's always inexperienced.

Comment: I think part of it is generation-related. I'm in my mid-thirties and I wouldn't consider being called a newbie as rude. I suspect many people in my age group or younger would feel similarly about this.

Comment: @cornishnjnja looking back at this 3 years later, "newbie" has sort of become obsolete in my experience. Now I hear "noob" more, and only in gaming-related situations

Comment: I wish I could agree 100%. Sadly, I can't. "Newbie" is still being used often enough in my experience, that it hasn't quite become obsolete. If someone calls you a "noob", or worse, a "n00b", then you're being mocked. As a side note, I play World of Warcraft. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> **Newbie:** someone who has just started doing an activity , a job , etc.: (The guide helps newbies understand the internet).
>
> **Novice:** a person who is not experienced in a job or situation : (I've never driven a car before - I'm a complete novice), (This is quite
>   a difficult plant for novice gardeners to grow).

Yes you can say "I am a novice in English" or "I am a newbie in English". You can also say "I am a beginner in English". Rookie is also a related word but it is used more commonly in jobs and sports context.